# C loop with an increment

Tags: c

how can I do an increment when a range is given for conversion? Following is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int disrange(float x, float y);

    int main()
    {

        printf("The conversion from miles to km are:");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Miles  kilometers");
        printf("\n");

        // Set the range in Miles
        disrange(1,5,incr);  ---> extra params increment
 }    
    int disrange(float x, float y)
    {
       int a;

       for(a=x; a<=y; a++){
           // convert each value into km
           float b = a*1.61;        
           printf("%d   %f\n",a,b);
       }
    }
```

When the increment is `2`, the print out should be conversion for `1, 3, 5`. Thanks!!

Comment: Get it to compile first

Comment: something like a += increment

Comment: Why use 1.61 when you could just as easily use 1.609344?

Comment: @jarmod what's the difference?

Comment: @ngMan The question might better be titled "How do I make a C loop with a custom increment"

Comment: @Riet thanks, is there anyway for me to output the result in proper table format? consist 2 columns Miles and KM.

Comment: @ngMan A mile is closer to 1.609344 kilometers than 1.61. Not important if you're doing a quick estimate, but if you try using it to go around the world, you've gone 16 miles too far. Since they both use the same amount of memory, there's no cost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int disrange(float x, float y,float inc)
{
   int a;

   for(a=x; a<=y; a+=inc){
       // convert each value into km
       float b = a*1.61;        
       printf("%d   %f\n",a,b);
   }
}
```

If you want it in table format, try:

```
int disrange(float x, float y,float inc)
{
   int a;

   for(a=x; a<=y; a+=inc){
       // convert each value into km
       float b = a*1.61;        
       printf("%6d\t%07.5f\n",a,b);
   }
}
```

This will make the first field a minimum of 6 characters long, with the second 7 characters long with five after the decimal place. See [here](https://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm) for more information on printf